# simple array comparison logic fail

Tags: ruby

The idea is simple: If "red", "green", "orange", or "yellow" is input then Message passes.

The result I am getting is that it is failing. Also, I would like to randomly choose one color in the `colors` array.

I believe using this would work:

```
colors = [].sample

colors = ["red", "green", "orange", "yellow", "blue", "purple"]


correct_guesses = ["red","green","orange","yellow"]
total_guesses = 10

print "Enter your guess: "
guess = gets.chomp

if correct_guesses.include?(colors)
  puts "You got it right."
else
  puts "You got it wrong. Guess again."
end
```

Comment: Your `if` test to check what the user typed in, doesn't reference the `guess` variable containing what the user typed in...

Comment: Also, given your code I don't think `colors` is actually useful

Comment: Any way to clean this code up?


`if guess == "red" || guess == "green" || guess == "orange" || guess == "yellow"
  puts "You got it right."
else
  puts "You got it wrong. Guess again."
end`

Comment: @user1552815, "`if guess == "red" || guess == "green" || guess == "orange" || guess == "yellow"`" can be rewritten using `colors.any? { |c| c == guess }` or `colors.include?(guess)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically asking does any element of `colors` equal the object `correct_guesses`.

So on paper that looks like this:

does `["red", "green", "orange", "yellow", "blue", "purple"]` include the array `["red","green","orange","yellow"]`?

The answer is false.  `colors` is only one array of 6 string elements.

So what would pass as `true` in this scenario?  You could make it pass if `colors` had a second array like this:

```
colors = [["red", "green", "orange", "yellow"], "blue", "purple"]
```

That is obviously problematic, now red, green orange & yellow are all coupled together, we need them to be in the same group or create other permutations in order make this pass.

That said, I think we all get what you're trying to do here.  You're writing this as "does anything in the list `correct_guesses` match anything in the list colors".

That inherently means we need to loop through each array in order to get that outcome.

```
if includes_any?(colors, correct_guesses)
  puts "you are correct"
else
  puts "you got it wrong"
end
```

Then you'd just write a function to make the check like this:

```
def includes_any(colors, correct_guesses)
  correct_guesses.each do |guess|
    return true if colors.include?(guess)
  end
  false
end
```

This example doesn't have anything to do with user input because you're original code seems to bypass the `guess` variable so I omitted it as well.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to say is

```
if correct_guesses.include?(guess)
```

That will check if your guess is correct, by checking every element in the `correct_guesses` array.

`guess` is the variable that is assigned the value of what you are typing into the console.

This will also work

```
if correct_guesses.any?{|g| g == guess}
```

This will check if any element in the `correct_guesses` array is equal to the value the user typed in.